# Is it OK to ask about map encoding on GD?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question that is not exactly listed in the game development topics. To be more specific, I would like to ask a question about making map editors for other games and how to understand the encoding of the maps. Is this question OK to be asked here or does this question fit a different site, or perhaps reddit or some other forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:
You can ask, but it just barely seems on topic and might be closed.

Longer version:
If it's about some specific application, and you are asking how that particular application is encoding it's maps, here is not a good place to ask.

On the other hand, if you are designing some map editor for yourself, and wondering what should be considered in creating your own map file (which seems to be the case here), I would say it's in the gray area.

A better question might be something like describing your game, and asking what should be stored for that specific game.

The general rule of thumb in this site is:

1. A question should be specific about what the problem is, and
2. The problem should have some specific solution, which is not immediately obvious just by a mere google search.

Of course the question obviously should be about some Game-Development topic, that in your case it is.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be on topic to ask how Unity encodes maps and how should I make a map editor for a unity game?

Comment: I'm not sure about the first part (how unity encodes). But it seems the second part is.